In Go, how can I delay the ctrl+c interuption
I would like to run my function doSomething and when someone hits control+c the program does not exit yet but waits 5 seconds before doing so.
func createTunnel(x string) {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println(sig)

        // Wait for 5 seconds before closing the tunnel
        fmt.Println("Received CTRL+C, waiting 5 seconds before closing the tunnel...")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        done <- true
    }()

    // Run the tunnel creation and keep it until 5s will pass after control + c
    common.doSomething("test")

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}

I'm new to Go. Thank you in advance.
[EDIT]
common.doSomething("test") function actually opens the tunnel to some external resources and the end state would be to ask a user is he /she is sure to close the tunnel, waiting for 5s is just because I thought it would be easier to accomplish and then I could work on top of that. So the goal flow would be to: 1. run the tunnel 2. if someone hits ctrl+c ask if he/she want to finish the tunnel connection 3. if yes, finish, if no, leave it.

Hey @murakami, could you please elaborate a bit more on what are you trying to achieve? As I see, your code will behave in the way you asked.
The common.doSomething() will execute. And the program will hold until control+c is signalled.

BTW: Consider signal.NotifyContext(some_context, os.Interrupt). I'm just guessing here, but you seem to be doing something in the background, which you want to cancel with 5s delay. For that, Go provides contexts though.

Where is the problem? If you want to cancel common.DoSmth you will have to implement it there or start it as a goroutine.

I've added EDIT section in the original question. Sorry for misguiding.

Ok. How would you write a function that implements what you describe ? the "ask if he/she ..." part

I think I understand what are you aiming at.
And you are almost there. You have successfully managed to catch the signal with your goroutine that waits for the sig := <- sigs signal.
When you invoke done <- true you are efficiently ending the program.
I know I am speaking the obvious, just stating the steps.
What you need presumably is the goroutine not ending depending on the user outcome.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    createTunnel("creating a tunnel")
}

func createTunnel(x string) {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case sig := <-sigs:
                fmt.Println()
                fmt.Println(sig)

                // Here instead of closing the program with done <- true we can ask the user what he wants?
                fmt.Println("Do you want to close the tunnel? (y/n)")
                var input string
                _, err := fmt.Scanln(&input)
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }

                if input == "y" {
                    done <- true
                } else {
                    continue
                }

            }
        }

    }()

    go doSomething(x)

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}

func doSomething(x string) {
    fmt.Println("I am doing something: ", x)
}


I mostly reused your code, with minimum additions.
The most notable you will see is the
for {
    select {
    case sig := <- sigs
    }
}

setup.
What that does for you is spin the goroutine in a loop with the select statement handling the Go channels. I recommend reading a bit more on the select statement and some examples on how to work with channels. Probably reading on how context.WithCancel() works should give you the right idea.
Also, please do keep in mind that going manual with fmt.Println() and fmt.Scanln() could probably not lead to the best user experience out there. I recommend checking out cli tools like https://github.com/spf13/cobra for creating really cool cli tools.

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "bufio"
    "common" // Assuming "common" is your package with doSomething function
)

func createTunnel(x string) {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println(sig)

        // Ask the user if they want to close the tunnel
        fmt.Println("Received CTRL+C, do you want to close the tunnel? (y/n)")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        if input == "y\n" || input == "Y\n" {
            fmt.Println("Closing the tunnel in 5 seconds...")
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            done <- true
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Tunnel will remain open")
        }
    }()

    // Run the tunnel creation and keep it until user confirms closure
    common.doSomething("test")

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}

func main() {
    createTunnel("test")
}


I guess this what you were looking for, used above solution itself and
modified to your need


Please explain how this wall of code solve the issue at hand. Code-only answer are not good answers
